# How does AES-CCM work in BitLocker?

Tags: aes, ccm

I'm studying this white-paper: http://jessekornblum.com/publications/di09.pdf

The author says that using AES-CCM with the external key (highlighted in green at page 9, figure 4) and with the nonce at offset `0x3662B8` (highlighted in red, figure 5) you can decrypt the data at offset `0x3662D4`.

I don't understand how AES-CCM works in BitLocker. Can someone please explain it to me?

I have the following doubts:

1. The length of IV should be of 16 bytes, but I have a nonce of 12 bytes.
2. How is the MAC calculated?

Comment: The octet length of the CCM nonce is not 16 but $15-L$, where $L$ equals the octet length of the counter.

Comment: Don't you understand CCM in BitLocker, or don't you understand CCM at all? Explain CCM is a bit broad.

Comment: I don't understand CCM in BitLocker